# shutting down an OS without using API's

Tags: c, api, operating-system, shutdown

I was trying to add a shutdown feature to my home-made OS , but I don't really have such API yet .
I was wondering how does the OS's terminates the power?

Comment: I don't think i understand...do you mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352698/what-happens-during-the-shutdown-process-of-an-os ?

Comment: Yes . But im trying to write its api . Something simple not like transmitting the ram to hard and then shut down or ...  . Just unplug the power And terminate the os thread .

Comment: Well, try the power switch or reset. Seriously: how do you think to shut down a computer by software without an interface for that software? If you have not stored anything on disk or written everything, just stop and turn off the computer. That's actually what other systems used to do when computers had proper power switches and no "soft-off" (pre-ATX).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your low level code to shut down the *hardware* is going to depend on the architecture. For shutting down an i386 device with a BIOS, INT 15h is the vector that is eventually used by OS monitors.

You should consider APM and ACPI schemes for power management, graceful shutdown of peripherals with power management, and poweroff considerations in multi-processor systems.

I expect that others will give answers leading you to examine Linux APM and ACPI code. In i386 kernels there is a very straightforward apm_power_off() function in arch/x86/kernel/apm_32.c which does an INT 15 shutdown.